# Nesting controllers and directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am struggling to define a good approach for the following scenario:

I have an AngularJs app that consumes a Laravel built api.

My tasks index page lists out tasks. At the bottom of the list is a new entry line where the two basic requirements of a task can be entered, and a new task is created (via a service that calls my API), and the item pushed into scope.

The complication comes here - when a user clicks on an existing task, a sidebar opens which shows ALL of the details of the task. All details are editable, and include adding subtasks, attachments etc. They need to click save to call the API update method, but because the task is updating in the list as they make changes in the sidebar, people are thinking it's already saving. I'd like to separate the scope of the tasks list from the task sidebar somehow - but then obviously update the list when a task is saved.

My TasksController is looking quite untidy. At the moment, I have an ng-click function that creates a 'selectedTask' variable (using the task selected), which is then used by the sidebar view.

I know there will be a better way. I have tried creating a new controller for the task sidebar, with a directive - but am struggling to see how I can pass the data back and forth.

Some code to help understand where I am coming from:

**app.js routes**

```
.state('root.tasks', {
    url: '/tasks',
    views: {
        'content@root': {
            templateUrl: '../partials/tasks-index.html',
            controller: 'TasksController as TasksCtrl'
        },
        'task-detail-sidebar@root.tasks': {
            templateUrl: '../partials/task-detail-sidebar.html'
        }
    }
})
```

**TasksController show Task function**

```
vm.showTask = function(task, added) {
// if same task is clicked in list again, or close button clicked, close task
if (vm.selectedTask.id == task.id && vm.clickedShut == false && !added) {
    vm.clickedShut = true;
} else {
    // else open task sidebar and create selectedTask
    vm.clickedShut = false;
    task.newSubtask = {'title':'', 'assignees':[task.task_owner]};
    vm.selectedTask = task;

    // need to grab current owner/assignees so we know if they change when saving - if so, notifications are sent
    vm.currentOwner = task.task_owner.id;
    vm.currentAssignees = [];
    if (task.assignees) {
        for (var i = 0; i < task.assignees.length; i++) {
            vm.currentAssignees.push(task.assignees[i].id);
        }
    }
}
```

};

**TasksController updateTask**

```
vm.updateTaskFromSidebar = function() {
    TasksService.update(vm.selectedTask).then(function(data) {
       if (data.data.task_owner.id !== vm.currentOwner && data.data.task_owner.id !== $rootScope.currentUser.id) {
           NotificationsService.updateOwner(data.data, $rootScope.currentUser)
       }
        var newAssignees = data.data.assignees;
        var alertAssignees = [];
        if (newAssignees) {
           for (var i = 0; i < newAssignees.length; i++) {
               if (vm.currentAssignees.indexOf(newAssignees[i].id) === -1 && newAssignees[i].id !== data.data.task_owner.id && newAssignees[i].id !== $rootScope.currentUser.id) {
                   alertAssignees.push(newAssignees[i]);
               }
           }
           if (alertAssignees.length) {
               NotificationsService.updateAssignees(data.data, alertAssignees, $rootScope.currentUser);
           }
       }
        vm.showSimpleToast('Task Saved');
    }).catch(function() {
        vm.showAlertDialog('Error Updating Task', "We've spotted this and will work to resolve the problem as soon as possible.");
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clone the task object in the sidebar using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(task)) and put the cloned object on the scope of the sidebar. This happens once in the sidebar controller and all inputs should update the cloned object.

When a user clicks save you copy back to the real task keys that have changed. You can use extend for example for this. The actual save can be done in the sidebar controller or you could emit an event on the rootScope and listen for the event in the tasks controller.

Comment: I thought about event listeners but there are going to huge numbers of tasks - will this not cause a performance issue watching for events constantly? I can clone the task - but how do I get it back?

Comment: You watch for a Task update event once in the task controller or better yet in the task service. It has nothing to do with the number of tasks you have. You can send the updated task id and details as arguments of the event. Just remember to copy the attributes back to the original task (and not replacing the task) so that your bindings will continue to work. You can do this kind of copy with extend.

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a go as well

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to complete the answer of @Nitzo, instead of using events, you should create a service for your tasks.

When the user click on a task, you should clone it (you can user [angular.copy()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) or the JSON approach) and save the cloned task and the original task in the service.

When the user save the task, you get the cloned task (which the user has changed/updated) and merge it with the original object (you can user [angular.extend()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend)).

Since it's a service you can share it among all Controllers with no problem. You can use the snippet as a guideline =). (I still got alot to improve in my angular skills, if you find difficult to undestand the pattern I used checkout this awesome [angular-styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md), and if I miss used something please correct me)

```js
angular.module('main', [])
  .factory('taskService', taskService)
  .controller('TaskListController', TaskListController)
  .controller('TaskFormController', TaskFormController);

function taskService() {
 var service = {
  selectedTask: null,
  editingTask: null,
  tasks: [],
  load: load
 };

 function load() {
  service.tasks = [{name: "t1", value: 1}, {name: "t2", value: 1}]
 }

 return service;
}

TaskListController.$inject = ['taskService'];
function TaskListController(taskService) {
 var vm = this;

 vm.taskService = taskService;
 vm.editTask = editTask;
    taskService.load();

 function editTask(task) {
  taskService.selectedTask = task;
  taskService.editingTask = angular.copy(task);
 }

}

TaskFormController.$inject = ['taskService'];
function TaskFormController(taskService) {
 var vm = this;

 vm.taskService = taskService;
 vm.saveTask = saveTask;

 function saveTask() {
      if (taskService.selectedTask) {
  angular.extend(taskService.selectedTask, taskService.editingTask);
  taskService.selectedTask = null;
      } else {
        taskService.tasks.push(taskService.editingTask);
      }
      
      taskService.editingTask = null;
 }

}
```

```css
.task_item {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="main">

 <ul ng-controller="TaskListController as listCtrl">
  <li ng-repeat="task in listCtrl.taskService.tasks" 
   ng-click="listCtrl.editTask(task)" class="task_item">
   {{task.name}} - {{task.value}}
  </li>
 </ul>
 
 <form ng-controller="TaskFormController as formCtrl" ng-submit="formCtrl.saveTask()">
  <input type="text" placeholder="name" ng-model="formCtrl.taskService.editingTask.name"></input>
  <input type="number" placeholder="value"  ng-model="formCtrl.taskService.editingTask.value"></input>
  <input type="submit"></input>
 </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this seems like a good solution. For completeness and for others who may come across this could you provide some code? I'd happily mark as correct then.

Comment: Why not? Just posted the snippet =), tell me if that's what you were looking for/expecting